# Moving SQL Server databases from one drive to another?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 on my machine which stores everything on the C: drive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA). I got an additional Hard Drive now and would like to move all the databases over.

It's 26 databases, so I'd like to avoid manually disconnecting/reconnecting them. Ideally I would just like to move them from C: and D: and tell SQL Server to look there.

Downtime is not an issue, I just don't want to do dozens of mouse clicks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I've seen about moving databases between disks involves manually detaching, moving, and reattaching the databases.  Alternatively, you can script it to do the same.